# Vagrant Chef Recipe Checksum Calculations

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, vagrant

I am running a mysql recipe that is failing.  When I do vagrant up after a halt it claims that  grants.sql template's checksum has changed causing it to re-run when it shouldn't.

```
[default] [Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] INFO: Processing template[/etc/mysql/grants.sql] action create (mysql::server line 128)
: stdout
[default] [Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] DEBUG: Current content's checksum:  3992e44304b56cebdbd4bf23183ddd78f877539c025227546e19098b0b5872ca
: stdout
[default] [Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] DEBUG: Rendered content's checksum: f967f212b3e7b25a08ed35d086938846c188f6e9980a1ecc42635136841587a4
: stdout
[default] [Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] INFO: template[/etc/mysql/grants.sql] backed up to /var/chef/backup/etc/mysql/grants.sql.chef-20120328125848
: stdout
[default] [Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] INFO: template[/etc/mysql/grants.sql] updated content
: stdout
[default] [Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] INFO: template[/etc/mysql/grants.sql] sending run action to execute[mysql-install-privileges] (immediate)
: stdout
[default] [Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] INFO: Processing execute[mysql-install-privileges] action run (mysql::server line 137)
: stdout
[default] [Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] INFO: execute[mysql-install-privileges] sh(/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p"evanta" < /etc/mysql/grants.sql)
: stdout
[default] [Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] ERROR: execute[mysql-install-privileges] (mysql::server line 137) has had an error
[Wed, 28 Mar 2012 12:58:48 -0700] ERROR: template[/etc/mysql/grants.sql] (/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/mysql/recipes/server.rb:128:in `rescue in from_file') had an error:
execute[mysql-install-privileges] (mysql::server line 137) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p"evanta" < /etc/mysql/grants.sql ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 12: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
---- End output of /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p"evanta" < /etc/mysql/grants.sql ----
Ran /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p"evanta" < /etc/mysql/grants.sql returned 1
```

Any ideas how these checksums are completed and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to debug these issues is to take a look at the new file it created, in this case at `/etc/mysql/grants.sql`, and then to look at the backup at `/var/chef/backup/etc/mysql/grants.sql.chef-20120328125848` (from the logs you posted). The backup is always made, so you can compare the contents of the two, and proceed to fix the Chef recipe to make sure it generates the same content.

Comment: Thanks!  That did it.  I was able to see that there was indeed a diff. Thanks @Mitchell

Comment: @NathanBrakk What did u changed to fix this?